# Docker Desktop: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: n. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: docker-desktop

I just installed Docker Desktop 4.19.0 but on startup this error message appeared:

[image]

Re-installation and re-starts did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling-Reinstalling worked for me.